# 403.18 - Forbidden The specified request cannot be processed in the application pool that is configured for this resource on the Web server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-5, iis-10

I don't understand why I get the error in the title of this post.

I have a Website running its own Application Pool in .NET V4.0.
Under the Website I have an Application running on its own Application Pool in "No Managed Code" as its a C# .NET 5.0 REST Web API. The Application points to a different physical location on the Server than the Website.

Why am I getting the following error when I navigate to the desired URL:

403.18 - Forbidden  The specified request cannot be processed in the application pool that is configured for this resource on the Web server.

When I try to call my REST service from POSTMAN using the correct URL I receive the following response from my server:

```
<TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE>
<BASE href="/error_docs/"><!--[if lte IE 6]></BASE><![endif]-->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
You do not have permission to access this document.
```

I have set the folder permissions correctly however, I'm still receiving this error.

Comment: The description is too brief. For example, I cannot reproduce it with some of my sites/apps. You might create simple sites/apps to test .NET 5 under ASP.NET 4 first, and then compare the failed/succeeded cases to see if anything you missed.

Answer (score 4):

There are many reasons for 403.18 error:

- An ISAPI filter or custom module changed the URL to run in a
  different application pool than the original URL.
- An ISAPI extension (or custom module) used ExecuteURL (or
  ExecuteRequest) to run in a different application pool than the
  original URL.
- You have a custom error page that is located in one application pool
  but is referenced by a Web site in another application pool. When the
  URL is processed, it is determined by IIS that that it should have
  been processed in the first application pool, not the other pool.
- The Web site has multiple applications configured. The application
  this request is configured to run in is set to run in an application
  pool that does not exist.

Things you can try:

- If you have an application that is trying to process a URL in another
  application pool (such as trying to process a custom error), ensure
  that they both run in the same application pool if appropriate.
- If you are trying to process a custom error URL that is located in
  another application pool, enable the custom errors Redirect feature.
- Verify that the application pool for the application exists.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status
  code and see if ExecuteURL is being called.

Comment: In my case, the application pool didn't exist.

Comment: In my case, UrlRewrite on higher level of application directory had different appPool than UrlRewrite at a lower level of application

Comment: In my case, my IIS 404 error setting was to execute a page using a relative url. Changed IIS response to redirect to a 404 page with absolute url.  Now the custom 404 error page is showing rather than the 403, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

For me a folder on my one virtual app was missing the dot net standard DLL. If the answer above doesn't resolve things it might be a good idea to beyond compare directories between the busted ENV and a working one.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and what worked for us was removing and adding the ISAPI filters via Add roles and features on our Windows 2019 server.